# Java web application classloader leak

Tags: java

I am trying to develop some shell scripts to manage a legacy application which is deployed on weblogic 10.3.6.

This script using weblogic wlst ant task to redeploy application after a patch is applyed. The problem is, after few times of redeployment, the OOM:PermGen will be raised. I use jvisualvm to monitor the PermGen space, found that every time I redeploy the application, PermGen space will be consumed more.The same problem happens with tomcat 8.5, then I use eclipse memory analyze tool to check the heap dump, found that `org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader` is taking lots of memory.

I know that a ClassLoader not garbage collected will cause all classes loaded by it also not garbage collected, but how can I know which object is holding a reference to `org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader`, the eclipse MAT showing it has following incoming reference:

```
Class Name                                                             |   Objects | Shallow Heap
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                       |           |             
org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader                   |         1 |          136
|- java.lang.Class                                                     |     6,123 |      114,928
|- java.lang.Package                                                   |       628 |       35,168
|- sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader                                   |        37 |        2,368
|- java.security.ProtectionDomain                                      |        53 |        2,120
|- org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread                      |        10 |        1,360
|- java.util.WeakHashMap$Entry                                         |         9 |          360
|- java.util.TimerThread                                               |         2 |          256
|- org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration                           |         1 |          176
|- org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread                               |         1 |          176
|- org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean                  |         2 |          176
|- java.util.ResourceBundle$LoaderReference                            |         5 |          160
|- org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|         1 |          120
|- org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext    |         1 |           96
|- java.net.URLClassLoader                                             |         1 |           80
|- org.apache.axis2.i18n.MessageBundle                                 |         1 |           48
|- java.util.Hashtable$Entry                                           |         1 |           32
|- java.lang.ref.WeakReference                                         |         1 |           32
|- java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$CacheKey                                |         1 |           32
'- Total: 18 entries                                                   |           |             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but what should I do next ?

Comment: I came across these articles on diagnosing classloader leaks.  Start here: http://java.jiderhamn.se/2011/12/11/classloader-leaks-i-how-to-find-classloader-leaks-with-eclipse-memory-analyser-mat/

Comment: @StephenC thanks, that blog helped, the problem is caused by axis2 shutdown hook thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach according to [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/489944/) resource.

Go to Dominator Tree and right-click on it to do either

Use Path To GC roots on each of the objects in turn (or Merge Shortest Paths to GC Roots on a set of objects) to find out why they are retained.